# Querying XML tree with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to parse out an complex XML file using LINQ. The files contains thousands of records, each with hundreds of fields. I need to parse out certain parts of information about each drug and store it in a database.

**Edit:**
I'm very sorry all, but the originally posted XML was in fact not accurate. I was unaware of the fact that the attributes would alter the process. I've updated the question to accurately portray the true nature of XML file.

Here's a sample of the XML:

```
<<drugs xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://drugbank.ca" xs:schemaLocation="http://www.drugbank.ca/docs/drugbank.xsd" schemaVersion="1.4">
   <drug>
      <name>foo</name>
      <indication>Some info here</indication>
      <half-life>1 to 3 hours</half-life>
      <protein-binding>90%</protein-binding>
        // hundreds of other elements
      <properties>
         <property>
            <kind>logP/hydrophobicity</kind>
            <value>-0.777</value>
         </property>
         <property>
            <kind>Molecular Weight</kind>
            <value>6963.4250</value>
         </property>
         <property>
            <kind>Molecular Formula</kind>
            <value>C287H440N80O110S6</value>
         </property>
         //dozens of other properties
      </properties>
   </drug>
   // thousands of more drugs
</drugs>
```

I'm pretty fuzzy on the actual querying, as this is my first time working with LINQ. I'm familiar with SQL, so the concept of complex queries aren't difficult for me, but I haven't been able to find any documentation that I can understand that helps with this issue. The query that I have so far is as follows:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"drugbank.xml");

var d = from drugs in xdoc.Descendants("drug")
                        select new
                        {
                            name = drugs.Element("name").Value,
                            indication = drugs.Element("indication").Value,
                            halflife = drugs.Element("half-life").Value,
                            proteinBinding = drugs.Element("protein-binding").Value,
                        };
```

The first issue is (theoretically) resolved. On to...

The second issue is the fact that I need to extract some of the properties (namely, hydrophobicity, molecular weight, and molecular formula), but where I'm confused is that the property kind and property value are stored in two different XElements. How can I get the property values restricted to the fields that I care about?

Comment: The sample you've given *doesn't* print out blank lines - it prints exactly what you'd expect. So you need to look at the difference between what you've posted and your real file. We can't help you there.

Comment: Tip: Use LINQPad to test your parsing code. It makes it really easy to `.Dump()` results of your subqueries bit by bit until you figure out where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a subquery to get the properties into another property of the outer generic object. If you want them nested:

```
XNamespace defaultNS = "http://drugbank.ca";

var d = from drugs in xdoc.Descendants(defaultNS + "drug")
        select new
        {
            name = drugs.Element(defaultNS + "name").Value,
            indication = drugs.Element(defaultNS + "indication").Value,
            halflife = drugs.Element(defaultNS + "half-life").Value,
            proteinBinding = drugs.Element(defaultNS + "protein-binding").Value,
            Properties = (from property in drugs.Element(defaultNS + "properties").Elements(defaultNS + "property")
                          let kind = property.Element(defaultNS + "kind").Value
                          where kind == "logP/hydrophobicity" || kind == "Molecular Weight" || kind == "Molecular Formula"
                          select new { Kind = kind, Value = property.Element(defaultNS + "value").Value })
        };
```

Or flattened:

```
XNamespace defaultNS = "http://drugbank.ca";

var d = from drugs in xdoc.Descendants(defaultNS + "drug")
        let properties = drugs.Element(defaultNS + "properties").Elements(defaultNS + "property")
        select new
        {
            name = drugs.Element(defaultNS + "name").Value,
            indication = drugs.Element(defaultNS + "indication").Value,
            halflife = drugs.Element(defaultNS + "half-life").Value,
            proteinBinding = drugs.Element(defaultNS + "protein-binding").Value,
            hydrophobicity = (from property in properties
                          let kind = property.Element(defaultNS + "kind").Value
                          where kind == "logP/hydrophobicity"
                          select property.Element(defaultNS + "value").Value).FirstOrdefaultNS(),
            molecularWeight = (from property in properties
                          let kind = property.Element(defaultNS + "kind").Value
                          where kind == "Molecular Weight" || kind == "Molecular Formula"
                          select property.Element(defaultNS + "value").Value).FirstOrdefaultNS(),
            molecularFormula = (from property in properties
                          let kind = property.Element(defaultNS + "kind").Value
                          where kind == "Molecular Formula"
                          select property.Element(defaultNS + "value").Value).FirstOrdefaultNS()
        };
```

Also, a very useful reference that can help you learn about Linq is [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

Comment: So this worked very well with the sample data that I provided, thanks. However, for some strange reason that I can't figure out, it doesn't work with the actual file that I need to query, nothing is returned.

Comment: I've found the problem: the root note of the file has attributes, if I remove them the query works as intended. What I don't understand is why that makes a difference.

Comment: That seems strange. The only attribute that should change the matching behavior is if there was an xmlns attribute.

Comment: And that explains it. The devil's in the details, I'm updating the question with the verbatim root node.

Comment: Got it sorted, I added to `XNamespace` to all references to the files. Now it's working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: 9 times out of 10, the answer to no results in a LINQ to XML query is a missing namespace.

Comment: Edited answer to account for the default namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I've pasted your code:
output:

```
foo
Some info here
1 to 3 hours
90%
```

just as expected